# Json script is not responding without search

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to return data from my database to a `<table>`. The statement I am using to select the data is: `SELECT id, name, k_id FROM table`. In mysql this statement is returning 100 rows.

When I run the json script I can see that the script dont fills my `<table>`. It shows only data when I search for data in the table: `if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {`.

With the search the SQL statement becomes like:

```
SELECT id, name, k_id FROM table WHERE ( k_id LIKE '100' OR name LIKE '100')
```

The SQL statement with search is showing me data.

Does someone know why my table is empty when I try to run the statement `SELECT id, name, k_id FROM table` without the `search` option?

Here is my full script:

```
<?php
    include_once("connection.php");
    $params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

    $params = $_REQUEST;

    //define index of column
    $columns = array( 
        0 => 'id',
        1 => 'k_id', 
        2 => 'name'
    );

    $where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

    // check search value exist
    if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
        $where .=" WHERE ";
        $where .=" ( k_id LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR name LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%')";
    }

    if (!empty($where) ) {

   $where .= " ";
    } else {
     $where .= " ";
    }

    // getting total number records without any search
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, k_id FROM table ";
    $sqlTot .= $sql;
    $sqlRec .= $sql;
    //concatenate search sql if value exist
    if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

        $sqlTot .= $where;
        $sqlRec .= $where;
    }

    $sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

    $queryTot = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));

    $totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

    $queryRecords = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

    //iterate on results row and create new index array of data
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
        $data[] = $row;
    }   

    $json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
            "data"            => $data
            );

    echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
?>
```

Comment: Can you please `echo` your both the queries and share `output`.

Comment: yes echo `$sqlTot`, `$queryTot)`, $sqlRec` with and without where along with `$totalRecords `

Comment: How can I echo them? I just get `error to fetch employees data` when I add the echo`s at the bottom of the page after `echo json_encode($json_data)`

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: Still not fixed